# Combining Columns Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I am trying to combine two Columns in a df but keep a space between the two values

For the df below I can combine them through the following.

```
d = ({
    'A' : ['Foo','Bar','Foo'],     
    'B' : ['A','B','C'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df["Com"] = df["A"].map(str) + df["B"]
```

Output:

```
     A  B   Com
0  Foo  A  FooA
1  Bar  B  BarB
2  Foo  C  FooC
```

But I'd like a space in between. So the intended Output is:

```
     A  B    Com
0  Foo  A  Foo A
1  Bar  B  Bar B
2  Foo  C  Foo C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add new string with space:

```
df["Com"] = df["A"].map(str) + ' ' + df["B"]
print (df)
     A  B    Com
0  Foo  A  Foo A
1  Bar  B  Bar B
2  Foo  C  Foo C
```

Python 3.6 solution:

```
df["Com"] = [f'{i} {j}' for i, j in zip(df["A"], df["B"])]
print (df)
     A  B    Com
0  Foo  A  Foo A
1  Bar  B  Bar B
2  Foo  C  Foo C
```

Python 3 solution:

```
df["Com"] = ['{} {}'.format(i, j) for i, j in zip(df["A"], df["B"])]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can simply get the output by

```
    df['Com']=df['A'] + ' ' + df['B']
```

python is smart enough.

Answer (score 0):

Just use apply function for DataFrame

```
df['Com'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['A']+' '+x['B'], axis=1)
df
Out[25]: 
     A  B    Com
0  Foo  A  Foo A
1  Bar  B  Bar B
2  Foo  C  Foo C
```